# Boolean algebra homomorphisms with adjoints

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders, topos-theory

I'm interested in a particular class of maps between boolean algebras: the homomorphisms $f:A\to B$ such that there exist functions (not necessarily homomorphisms) $u,d:B\to A$ such that

$$f(a)\leq b\Leftrightarrow a\leq u(b)\text{ and }b\leq f(a)\Leftrightarrow d(b)\leq a$$

i.e. such that $d\dashv f\dashv u$ when seen as functors between posets-as-categories.

### Have such homomorphisms been studied in the literature? What names are they known by?

I know that in topos theory there are similar concepts called [atomic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/atomic+geometric+morphism) and [essential](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essential+geometric+morphism) geometric morphisms (for boolean algebras "atomic" and "essential" morphisms are the same, since if a function $f$ is any two of (homomorphism, left-adjoint, right-adjoint) then it is also the third).

I also know that if $A$ is complete then these homomorphisms are precisely the ones that preserve all meets and joins (by the adjoint functor theorem).

Comment: These are "Galois Connections" -- nearly every work of Roland Backhouse concerns them and he is one of their main promoters in computing science.

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy Thanks. I know an adjunction between posets is called a Galois Connection, but I'm interested in particular in the case where one of the functions is a homomorphism between boolean algebras. Does Backhouse study that anywhere?

Comment: I recall him specifically working up to relation algebras, which includes Boolean algebras, so you'll likely find profit in reading some of his works --most of which are online.